# Detect window and view load using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have an old AngularJS application that we have converted to React (as we don't like the direction Angular has gone, and AngularJS seems abandoned and React seems more similar to how the older Angular worked for us).

One of the directives we had was to hide a splash element once the window and view content was detected to have finished/be ready like so:

```
.directive('loadingOverlay', ['$window', '$q', '$animate', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function($window, $q, $animate, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            priority: 500,
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                // hide the splash
                function finish() {
                    $('#splash').remove();
                }
                // detect the window load has finished loading
                var windowLoad = $q.defer();
                $($window).on('load', function() {
                    windowLoad.resolve();
                });
                // detect the view has finished loading
                var viewLoaded = $q.defer();
                scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
                    viewLoaded.resolve();
                });
                // once both have resolved, call finish
                $q
                    .all([windowLoad.promise, viewLoaded.promise])
                    .then(function (results) {
                        $timeout(finish, 1000);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Does React have something similar to `$q` and `$viewContentLoaded`?

Comment: I guess you're looking for [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: @hindmost Are we able to defer that though? So we can effectively wait for both the component mount and the window load...

Comment: No need for that since React loading/mounting only take place _**after**_ window load.